# How do I set Variables with Query for GraphQL in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, graphql-csharp

I can't seem to get this to work
I have the following code.

```
var query = new GraphQLRequest
            {
                
                Query = @"
  { 
    query ($pageSize : Int)
{
    studentQuery(skip:20, pageSize: $pageSize ){
    totalRecords
    pageInfo{
      hasNextPage
    }
    students{
      studentCursor
      studentCode
      firstName
      surname
      studentPlacements(placementStatuses:[""Offered"", ""Published"", ""Incomplete"", ""Cancelled"", ""Accepted"", ""Completed"", ""Withdrawn Education Provider"", ""Withdrawn Student""]){
        placementId
        startDate
        endDate
        publishedPersonnelEmail
        placementStatus
        placementAgencies{
          agencyCode
          agencyName
          agencyLevel
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
}
",
                Variables = new { pageSize = 10 },
                
            };
```

I can't for the life of me get it to work with variable for pageSize
I always get an error saying Expecting Name found $

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the outer {}
Now on to figuring out how to pass a data